# React useRef or module scope to store UI-independent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Let's say there is a UI-independent state called `currentSelected` in React functional component. It stores the currently selected item and will be used at some time.

There are two ways to store the state, `useRef hook` or module scope out of component.

**useRef hook:**

```
function Example() {
  const currentSelected = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    // access currentSelected state
  })

  function handleClick(item) {
    currentSelected.current = item
  }

  return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => <li onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>item.name</li>)}
      </ul>
  )
}
```

**module scope:**

```
let currentSelected = null
function Example() {

  useEffect(() => {
    // access currentSelected state
  })

  function handleClick(item) {
    currentSelected = item
  }

  return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => <li onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>item.name</li>)}
      </ul>
  )
}
```

Which method is more suitable for storing UI-independent state like `currentSelected`?

And what is the application scenario of `useRef` and module scope in storing state?

========= Update ===========

UI-independence means that you don't want to trigger re-render after updating the state. In contrast, UI related states do this.

Answer (score 12):

## The difference between `useRef` and a *module-scope variable*

Just for completeness sake, I'll throw in `useState` as well.

- `useState`: *immutable* data that's tied to the component instance and triggers render on change through the *setter* function.
- `useRef`: *mutable* data that's also tied to the component instance, but doesn't trigger any renders on change.
- A *module scope variable*: mutable data that's tied to the module, which also doesn't trigger any renders on change since it's completely outside of React.

## Use-case for `useRef`

If you're mounting a component more than once, e.g. using it on two pages, `useRef` will ensure that each component instance has its own mutable value.

```
// Here, the Example component could be used in multiple places
// and each instance would successfully keep its own state while
// not triggering renders on changes.
function Example() {
  const currentSelected = useRef()

  useEffect(() => { /* access currentSelected state */ })

  return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li onClick={() => { currentSelected.current = item }}>{item.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
  )
}
```

## Use-case for a module scope variable

If you're looking for a *singleton-like* pattern or a *static-like* variable, e.g. for some kind of app-wide shared data, then a *module scope variable* will make this possible, like in any vanilla JS module.

```
// Here, the count value will be initialized once and then shared between every
// instances across the app, ever.

let count = 0;
function Example() {
  // Won't trigger a render, so some Example instance could still show the old value.
  count += 1;

  return <span>Combined renders of all the Example components: {count}</span>;
}
```

*Note that it won't trigger a render when `count` changes, so you shouldn't use it like that.*

---

## The caveats

If used only once in a place where the component is also only mounted once, both patterns will appear to behave similarly, but in the end, it's a matter of time until something triggers a remount and then you'll be facing a weird bug.

You could also encounter problems when unit testing a module with a *module scope variable* in it since it may not be properly reset in-between test cases. A quick workaround is to just export the variable and let the test cases change its value, but be careful not to change it anywhere else. *Though this should be evaluated as a case-by-case basis.*

Answer (score 1):

**First one**

For myself choose the first one.Because its works as individual inside function.You could use multiple `example` component as same class/function .

```js
function check(a){
 let one = 'overwrite'+a;
 console.log(one)
}

check(1);
check(2);//as individual inside only
```

**Second one**

Its overwrite `currentSelected` variable on each example component execute

```js
let one = null
//second one
function check() {
  one = 'overwrite';
  console.log(one)
}

console.log('Before =' + one)
check();
console.log('After =' + one);
```

Answer (score -2):

why not use the useState hook. it's perfect for this secnario.

```
const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState();
...
{items.map(item => <li onClick={() => setCurrentItem(item)}>item.name</li>)}
```

another problem with your example is that when you change the ref current property in the handleClick it doesnt triggered render, so the useEffect in your function will not run so you cant access the ref.

Answer (score -2):

Your "currentItem" may be UI-independent, but it would be component-dependent. right? If currentItem is related to this component, you should use the React.useState hook. This is just what the state is for.

Global variables(not constants) should be avoided in OOP programming. For example, there would be only one global variable in well-written OOP code, i.e. theApp.

Comment: UI-independent state doesn't trigger re-render. And module scope is not **global**